# How to: Advanced Access query with a calculation based on two user inputs and two fields

Tags: sql, user-input

I would like to run a query on an Access table. The table has a column for X and a column for Y coordinates. I would like the user to be able to run the query, be prompted to type in their own X and Y coordinates, and then the query will return a new table ordered from closest to farthest from the user inputted X and Y. This is a bit out of my league, any help getting this to work would be much appreciated.

To better understand what I'm saying, the existing table might look like this:

```
PrimaryKey----------X----------Y

--------------1----------1----------2

--------------2----------7----------9

--------------3---------26---------31
```

And I would like the query to prompt the user to give an X and Y. If the user inputted X=8, Y=6 for example, the query would calculate the distance between the points:

```
sqrt((1-8)^2+(2-6)^2)=8.06

sqrt((7-8)^2+(9-6)^2)=3.16

sqrt((26-8)^2+(31-6)^2)=30.81
```

Then return based on these numbers:

```
PrimaryKey----------X----------Y

--------------2----------7----------9

--------------1----------1----------2

--------------3---------26---------31
```

Comment: Replace the 8 and 6 with the user inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replace the 8 and 6 with the user inputs and the other numbers with the field references.

```
SQR( ((X - [User Input for X]) ^ 2) + ((Y - [User Input for Y]) ^ 2) )
```